# conditional replacing rows with a number

Tags: text-processing

I have a directory containing nearly 11 million small files: like this

```
wa_filtering_DP15_good_pops_snps_file_1
wa_filtering_DP15_good_pops_snps_file_2
.
.
.
wa_filtering_DP15_good_pops_snps_file_11232111
```

and each file has only 2 rows and 315 columns looks like this:

```
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   1   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I want to go through each file and if in each column both rows have 0 values replace them with 9 and get something like this:

```
1   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   1   2   1   
0   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   0   0   0
```

Can someone help me out to figure out how to do that?
Thanks

Comment: With millions of small files, you're at risk of running out of inodes. Check with `df /path/to/files` versus `df -i /path/to/files`

Comment: I have a suspicion you would be better off rearchitecting, perhaps just to set up a database, but there's not enough information here to diagnose the *real* situation.  ;)  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `awk` solution.

```bsh
awk '{split($0,ary1,/[ ]+/); getline x; split(x,ary2,/[ ]+/); 
    for (i in ary1)if (!(ary1[i]+ary2[i])){ary1[i]=ary2[i]=9}} 
END{for (r=1;r<=NF;r++) printf ("%d ", ary1[r]); printf"\n"; 
    for (z=1;z<=NF;z++) printf ("%d ", ary2[z]); printf"\n"}' infile
```

**Explanations:**

- `split($0,ary1,/[ ]+/);`: reads and splits the first line into an array `ary1` with one-or-more spaces delimiters between.
- `getline x; split(x,ary2,/[ ]+/);`: reads the second line into variable `x` and split it into array `ary2`.
- `for (i in ary1)if (!(ary1[i]+ary2[i])){ary1[i]=ary2[i]=9}}`: loop in array `ary1` for each index in `i` if sum of both fields value were *zero* (`!(0)`will trigger `if(1)` as true condition) then set both fields value to `9`.
- `for (r=1;r<=NF;r++) printf ("%d ", ary1[r]); printf"\n";`: Now print final values of each array `ary1` and in next line `ary2`.

---

To apply on all ~11 million files, just save changes in `FILENAME.out` format where FILENAME indicate current input fileName reading by `awk`.

```bsh
awk '{split($0,ary1,/[ ]+/); getline x; split(x,ary2,/[ ]+/); 
    for (i in ary1)if (!(ary1[i]+ary2[i])){ary1[i]=ary2[i]=9}} 
END{for (r=1;r<=NF;r++) printf ("%d ", ary1[r])>FILENAME".out"; printf"\n">FILENAME".out"; 
    for (z=1;z<=NF;z++) printf ("%d ", ary2[z])>FILENAME".out"
}' wa_filtering_DP15_good_pops_snps_file_{1..11232111}
```

Comment: If any number can be negative, then the sum of two numbers may be zero without any of them being zero...

Comment: this one OP not mentioned yet, will update once he confirmed if has negative values, just simply change condition to `ary1[i]==0 && ary2[i]==0` :  )

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
NR == 1 {   # save the values from 1st line in array t
            split($0, t, FS);
        }

NR == 2 {   # compare values from second line with those stored in array t
            for ( i = 1; i <= NF; ++i ) {
                # build l1 and l2 (line 1 and line 2) based on comparison
                if ($i == 0 && t[i] == 0) {
                    l1 = (i == 1 ? 9    : l1 OFS 9    );
                    l2 = (i == 1 ? 9    : l2 OFS 9    );
                } else {
                    l1 = (i == 1 ? t[i] : l1 OFS t[i] );
                    l2 = (i == 1 ? $i   : l2 OFS $i   );
                }
            }
        }

END     {   # output the two constructed lines
            print l1;
            print l2;
        }
```

Running it on the example file:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
1 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 1 2 1
0 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 0 0 0
```

Running on all files matching `wa_filtering_DP15_good_pops_snps_file_*` in current directory:

```
mkdir modified

for name in wa_filtering_DP15_good_pops_snps_file_*; do
    awk -f script.awk "$name" >"modified/$name.new"
done
```

This will create a new file for each input file, with the name of the original file and an extra `.new` suffix. The new files will be placed in the `modified` folder in the current directory.

- I opted for creating new files so that the originals are left unmodified.
- I opted to put the new files in a new directory, as having 22 million files in a single directory could make the filesystem be a bit awkward to work with.

In general, try not to create millions of files in a single directory. Instead either

1. create many subdirectories and distribute the files in them, maybe based on a binning algorithm working on that last integer of the filename, or a hash, or
2. create a single output file that aggregates all data, possibly with extra lines of text identifying what the following two lines refer to.

---

The following variant will be more efficiently run on *millions* of files:

```
FNR == 1    {   # save the values from 1st line in array t
                split($0, t, FS);
            }

FNR == 2    {   # compare values from second line with those stored in array t
                for ( i = 1; i <= NF; ++i ) {
                    # build l1 and l2 (line 1 and line 2) based on comparison
                    if ($i == 0 && t[i] == 0) {
                        l1 = (i == 1 ? 9    : l1 OFS 9    );
                        l2 = (i == 1 ? 9    : l2 OFS 9    );
                    } else {
                        l1 = (i == 1 ? t[i] : l1 OFS t[i] );
                        l2 = (i == 1 ? $i   : l2 OFS $i   );
                    }
                }

                # create output filename based on input filename
                # and output the two lines
                f = "modified/" FILENAME ".new";
                print l1 >f;
                print l2 >f;
            }
```

To run it:

```
mkdir modified

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'wa_filtering_DP15_good_pops_snps_file_*' \
    -exec awk -f script.awk {} +
```

The new files will be generated in the `modified` folder as before, but this time only a fraction of `awk` processes will be started and the speed of processing will be greatly increased.

Comment: I simplified your for loop body to this: `        up = t[i];
        low = $i;

        if (up == 0 && low == 0) {
            up = 9; 
            low = 9;
        }

        if(i != 1) {
            up = OFS up;    
            low = OFS low;
        }

        l1 = l1 up;
        l2 = l2 low;
`. Clearer and cleaner, in my opinion. Plus, one **if** test less.

Comment: @MiniMax That may be a good modification, I agree. I will fix it as soon as I have spare time on my hands (busy ATM).

Answer (score 1):

For kicks, here's Ruby

```
ruby -e '
    data = File.readlines(ARGV.shift)
               .map {|line| line.split.map(&:to_i)}
               .transpose
               .map {|(a,b)| (a==0 && b==0) ? [9,9] : [a,b]}
               .transpose
               .each {|row| puts row.join(" ")}
' file
```

```
1 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 1 2 1
0 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 0 0 0
```

To replace all the files:

```
ruby -e '
    require "tempfile"
    require "pathname"
    Pathname.new("/path/to/your/files/").each_child do |pathname|
        next unless pathname.file?
        temp = Tempfile.new(pathname.basename.to_s)
        filename = pathname.to_s
        File.readlines(filename)
            .map {|line| line.split.map(&:to_i)}
            .transpose
            .map {|(a,b)| (a==0 && b==0) ? [9,9] : [a,b]}
            .transpose
            .each {|row| temp.puts row.join(" ")}
        temp.close
        File.link filename, filename+".bak"
        File.rename temp.path, filename
    end
'
```

Comment: You may not want the `File.link` step if you're running out of inodes.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative approach, which might be slow for million of files compared to pure awk solutions.

Using something like this, you can transpose rows to columns:

```
$ cat file1
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   1   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

$ paste -d'-' <(head -n1 file1 |tr -s ' ' '\n') <(tail -n1 file1 |tr -s ' ' '\n')
1-0
0-0
0-0
0-0
0-0
0-0
0-0
0-0
0-0
0-0
1-0
2-0
1-0
```

You can then replace all `0-0` occurences with `9-9` with a simple sed, and you can store the output to a temp variable:

```
$ f1=$(sed 's/0-0/9-9/g' <(paste -d'-' <(head -n1 file1|tr -s ' ' '\n') <(tail -n1 file1 |tr -s ' ' '\n')))
$ echo "$f1"
1-0
9-9
9-9
9-9
9-9
9-9
9-9
9-9
9-9
9-9
1-0
2-0
1-0
```

You can now revert back from columns to rows like:

```
$ awk -F'-' 'NR==FNR{printf "%s ",$1;p=1;next}p{printf "\n";p=0}{printf "%s ",$2}END{printf "\n"}' <(echo "$f1") <(echo "$f1")
1 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 1 2 1  
0 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 0 0 0
```

And you can also append `>file1` at the end of last awk command to overwrite the `file1` with the new contents.

Only thing left is to loop over all files. Can be done with a kind of bash loop:

```
for f in ./wa_filtering_DP15_good_pops_snps_file_*;do
  f1=$(sed 's/0-0/9-9/g' <(paste -d'-' <(head -n1 "$f"|tr -s ' ' '\n') <(tail -n1 "$f" |tr -s ' ' '\n')))
  awk -F'-' 'NR==FNR{printf "%s ",$1;p=1;next}p{printf "\n";p=0}{printf "%s ",$2}END{printf "\n"}' <(echo "$f1") <(echo "$f1") #>"$f" #uncomment >"$f" to overwrite the files...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

#### First variant:

For single file:

```
datamash -W transpose < input.txt | sed 's/0\t0/9\t9/' | datamash transpose
```

For many files do the same in the loop:

```
for i in *; do datamash -W transpose < "$i" |
sed 's/0\t0/9\t9/' |
datamash transpose > "new_$i"; done
```

This loop will create the new, changed file for the each file, with the prefix "new_" added. Then you can remove all old files and remove prefix "new_" from filenames.

#### Second variant:

This is a solution for the single file, for multiple files use loop, as in the previous variant.

```
tr '\n' '\t' < input.txt |
awk '{
    num = NF / 2;
    for(up = 1; up <= NF; up++) {
        if(up <= num) {
            low = num + up;
            if(!$up && !$low) {
                $up = 9;    
                $low = 9;
            }
        }

        printf "%s\t", $up;

        if(up % num == 0) 
            print "";
    }
}'
```

**Explanation**

1. `tr '\n' '\t' < input.txt` - join two lines together.
2. `awk`

   - checks the one element from the first line and the adjacent element from the second line simultaneously, like: **1** and **316**, **2** and **317**, **3** and **318**, so on.
   - if both elements are **0**, it changes them to **9**.
   - print fields by the order - **1, 2, 3, 4 ... 628, 629, 630**.
   - Each time the element number is a multiple of the number of elements in the line, adds a new line.

**Input**

```
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

**Output**

```
1   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   1   2   1
0   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   0   0   0
```

Comment: 'for i in *' is probably not a valid solution for 11 million files.  Use xargs instead.

Comment: @RonJohn `*` will only be a problem if the shell uses it to execute an external command. `for i in *` will not be a problem on 11 million files in itself.

Comment: But the '*' will expand in the bash command buffer, certainly overflowing it.

Comment: @RonJohn [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647755/2913477) is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not efficient enough for 11 million files but it's a different approach on the substitution. Takes one argument on the command line; the name of the **directory** where all of the files are stored. The name for the directory could  be hard coded instead (see notes in code). The base name for the file is already hard coded without the number at the end (not required).

```
#!/bin/bash

# compare two rows in a file
# when both are 0, change both to 9
# otherwise keep original value

ProgName=${0##*/}
Pid=$$
DBG_FNAME=""
scriptUsage() {
cat <<ENDUSE

  $ProgName </path/to/directory> [ [-d|--debug] || [-f|--filename] ]

  path/to/directory:    Path to directory (NO trailing '/')
  -f|--filename:        Print the each file name to stdout after complete
  -d|--debug:           Run in debug mode (Implies filename option - SEE NOTE*)
  -h|--help:            Print this help message

  NOTE:  USING [-d|--debug] AUTOMATICALLY SETS [-f|--filename]
         You DO NOT need both together!

ENDUSE
}

# check args
#!# NOTE: you can delete from here to #!!# above 'WorkDir="$1"'
[[ -z $1 ]] && { >&2 echo "MISSING file source directory!"; scriptUsage; exit 1; }
[[ $1 == "-h" || $1 == "--help" ]] && { scriptUsage; exit 0; }
[[ -d $1 ]] || { >&2 echo "Unable to locate directory [$1]"; exit 1; }
if (( $# > 2 ))
  then
    DBG_FNAME=1
    >&2 echo "Running in debug mode from using ${2} & ${3} together!"
    echo "PID is: $Pid"
    sleep 2
    set -x
  else
    [[ $2 == "-f" || $2 == "--filename" ]] && DBG_FNAME=1
    [[ $2 == "-d" || $2 == "--debug" ]] && { echo "PID is: $Pid"; set -x; }
fi
#!!# to here #!!#
# directory as arg[1] or change to hardcoded
  WorkDir="$1"

# check for/remove trailing slash
[[ ${WorkDir:(-1)} == / ]] && WorkDir=${WorkDir:0:((${#WorkDir}-1))}

# given file root withOUT number ending
  WorkFile="${WorkDir}/wa_filtering_DP15_good_pops_snps_file_"


##== MAIN LOOP
for file in ${WorkFile}*
  do
    # reset these after each file
    TopRow=""
    BotRow=""
    NewTop=""
    NewBot=""
    SKIPME=""

    # get top row of file
    TopRow=$(sed -n '1{p;q}' $file)
    # get bottom row of file
    BotRow=$(sed -n '2{p;q}' $file)

    ##-- EACH FILE LOOP
    for (( f=0; f<${#TopRow}; f++ ))
      do
        if [[ -n $SKIPME ]]
          then
            # SKIPME is -z by default so
            # this runs every other time through
            NewTop="${NewTop} "
            NewBot="${NewBot} "
            SKIPME=""
        elif (( $((${TopRow:${f}:1}+${BotRow:${f}:1})) == 0 ))
          then
            # 0+0=0 so change to 9
            NewTop="${NewTop}9"
            NewBot="${NewBot}9"
            SKIPME=1
        else
            # (1+0 or 0+1)!=0 so keep originals
            NewTop="${NewTop}${TopRow:${f}:1}"
            NewBot="${NewBot}${BotRow:${f}:1}"
            SKIPME=1
        fi
    done
    ##--

    # overwrite original file
    printf "%s\n%s" "$NewTop" "$NewBot" > $file

    # if -f|--filename given print file name
    [[ -n $DBG_FNAME ]] && echo "$file is complete"
done
##==
```

**DOES EDIT FILES IN PLACE.** Wouldn't be hard to have it make backups as it runs. Returns files exactly the way requested above.